# Collator not working on my mac

Tags: java, internationalization

I am trying to write some code that uses the Collator functionality in java to compare strings but my computer does not seem to be functioning properly. Here is the code:

```
Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
System.out.println( "ças vs zed: " + myCollator.compare("ças", "zed"));
System.out.println( "cas vs zed: " + myCollator.compare("cas", "zed"));
```

Here is what happens when I run this code on my computer:

```
ças vs zed: 1 
cas vs zed: -1
```

But when I run it on ideone.com I get the answer I want:

```
ças vs zed: -1
cas vs zed: -1
```

Here is the java version I am running on my computer (a Mac running OS X 10.6.8):

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

Why is my computer giving a different (wrong) result, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Here's a link to the ideone.com version: http://ideone.com/7zzN9

Answer (score 1):

I've just run it on my machine (a Mac running OS X 10.7.2 / Lion):

```
ças vs zed: -1
cas vs zed: -1
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

I'm running it with a UK locale.

Sorry that doesn't help, but shows it's not Mac specific - may be Snow Leopard though?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the Collator is initialized differently because of some result it gets from the OS?

What does Collator.getDecomposition() return on the two machines and the Collator you get back for the locale?

Comment: Both my computer and ideone.com return the same thing "Collator decomposition: 0".

Comment: Worth a try at least. Sorry it didn't take you forward.